# Word2Vec - How can I store and retrieve extra information regarding each instance of corpus?

Tags: deep-learning, gensim, word2vec, one-hot-encoding, word-embedding

I need to combine Word2Vec with my `CNN` model. To this end, I need to persist a flag (a binary one is enough) for each sentence as my corpus has two types (*a.k.a.* target classes) of sentences. So, I need to retrieve this flag of each vector after creation. How can I store and retrieve this information inside the input sentences of `Word2Vec` as I need both of them in order to train my deep neural network?

p.s. I'm using `Gensim` implementation of `Word2Vec`.

p.s. My corpus has **6,925** sentences, and `Word2Vec` produces **5,260** vectors.

**Edit:** More detail regarding my corpus (as requested):

The structure of the corpus is as follows:

1. sentences (label: `positive`) -- A **Python list**

   - `Feature-A`: **String**
   - `Feature-B`: **String**
   - `Feature-C`: **String**
2. sentences (label: `negative`) -- A **Python list**

   - `Feature-A`: **String**
   - `Feature-B`: **String**
   - `Feature-C`: **String**

Then all the sentences were given as the input to `Word2Vec`.

```
word2vec = Word2Vec(all_sentences, min_count=1)
```

I'll feed my CNN with the extracted features (which is the `vocabulary` in this case) and the `targets` of sentences. So, I need these labels of the sentences as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `Word2Vec` model doesn't retain any representation of the individual training texts, this is entirely a matter for you in your own Python code.

That doesn't seem like very much data. (It's rather tiny for typical `Word2Vec` purposes to have just a 5,260-word final vocabulary.)

Unless each text (aka 'sentence') is very long, you could even just use a Python dict where each key is the full string of a sentence, and the value is your flag.

But if, as is likely, your source data has some other unique identifier per text – like a unique database key, or even a line/row number in the canonical representation – you should use that identifier as a key instead.

In fact, if there's a canonical source ordering of your 6,925 texts, you could just have a list `flags` with 6,925 elements, in order, where each element is your flag. When you need to know the status of a text from position `n`, you just look at `flags[n]`.

(To make more specific suggestions, you'd need to add more details about the original source of the data, and exactly when/why you'd need to be checking this extra property later.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please, take a look at the edited OP.

Comment: I don't quite understand your addition. (Those aren't the kinds of list-of-tokens `Word2Vec` expects as `sentences`.) But the answer remains the same: you need to name/number your examples in some natural way, and then use your own basic Python data structure to look up the label for each instance.

Comment: Separately, `Word2Vec` & similar models are best trained with texts that don't have all texts of one type/theme/vocabulary in a consecutive clump. So before passing your texts to `Word2Vec` (or otherwise settling on a canonical ordering), you may want to be sure you're not passing them in as all-positive-examples, then all-negative-examples.

Comment: I'm passing all the sentences together, which are a `list` of `lists` (the `features`) that contain `Strings`, to the `Word2Vec`. I do have the targets of the sentences but the question is how can I match this raw data with the extracted vectors?

Comment: The `Word2Vec` model has nothing to report by text. It can only report vectors by word. What do you want to do with the word-vectors?

Comment: I'm passing the features of the analyzed Android apps in order to extract one-hot-encoded feature vectors. Then I feed my CNN with these vectors as it was described in this paper: itiis.org/digital-library/manuscript/2334

Comment: So are the app names potential unique IDs for each original text? If so, use them. If not, use some other unique ID to name the artifacts-of-interest. (But that's not really a `gensim` or `word2vec` matter, just Python wrangling of your separate data items.)

Comment: Yes, the package names of apps are unique but where should I store them in order to be able to match them with the vectors? In short, I need to match the vectors with these package names.

Comment: Match them with which vectors? The `Word2Vec` model only provides vectors per word. If you've somewhat created other vectors from a list-of-word (one text, or in your case one app), and that list-of-words is associated with unique name `xyz`, you can simply store the association 'xyz' -> your_calculated_vector_for_that_text inside a standard Python dict.